# How to turn enum values to strings in grpc-web

Tags: javascript, enums, grpc, enumeration, grpc-web

I have been working on a web application using React-Redux and gRPC. The server sends the frontend gRPC messages which the frontend receives with the enums in the form of integers. How can I turn these integer values to their corresponding string values?

I have tried the methods in the protoc generated `_pb.js` files `(.toObject(), get<Enum>()`, etc.)

```proto
message Example {
    ExampleType type = 2;
}

enum ExampleType {
    UNKNOWN_TYPE = 0;
    TEST_TYPE = 1;
    OTHER_TYPE = 2;
}
```

I expect the following shape of the `message.toObject()` JSON object:

```
{ type: string }
```

However, I receive the following:

```
{ type: integer }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you cannot get a string value for that.
web protobuf does that for a reason. If it allows string enum, there will be more code needed to specify those enum names, which is not good for code size.